# ¿Cómo calcular summarise sin contar los ceros?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un marco de datos de 7 variables y 715 observaciones. La estructura es la siguiente:

**ResumenOperadorPorMes**

```
$ Centro          : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Grupo           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Grupo 1", "Grupo 2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 
$ Operador        : chr  "Apellido 1, Nombre 1" "Apellido 1, Nombre 1"...
$ Año             : num  2018 2018 2018 2018 2019 ...
$ Mes             : num  2 3 4 8 2 1 2 3 4 5 ...
$ RatioTalkOver   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ RatioSilenceTime: num  0.3575 0.3572 0.1688 0.1188 0.0909 ...
```

Usando la librería `tidyverse` quiero hallar la `media` de las variables `RatioTalkOver` y `RatioSilenceTime`, el problema que estoy teniendo es que hay muchas observaciones de dichas variables que tienen el valor 0, y la media que está saliendo es muy pequeña, y no me cuadra.

Necesitaría que la media no tuviera en cuenta los ceros, puesto que hay meses en los que no tienen dato.

Lo que he hecho hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
summarise(
  group_by(ResumenOperadorPorMes, Centro),
  RatioTalkOver = mean(RatioTalkOver, na.rm = TRUE),
  RatioSilenceTime = mean(RatioSilenceTime, na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

He intentado filrarlo, pero sin éxito:

```
summarise(
  group_by(ResumenOperadorPorMes, Centro),
  RatioTalkOver = mean(RatioTalkOver > 0),
  RatioSilenceTime = mean(RatioSilenceTime > 0)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes reemplazar los `0` por `NA`, por ejemplo, mediante: `ifelse(RatioTalkOver==0, NA, RatioTalkOver)` y aprovechar que con `mean()` puedes ignorarlos:

```
summarise(
    group_by(ResumenOperadorPorMes, Centro),
    RatioTalkOver = mean(ifelse(RatioTalkOver==0, NA, RatioTalkOver), na.rm = TRUE),
    RatioSilenceTime = mean(ifelse(RatioSilenceTime==0, NA, RatioSilenceTime), na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

Con respecto a hacer: `mean(RatioTalkOver > 0)`  no te funciona por que `RatioTalkOver > 0` simplemente termina siendo un vector de lógicos y no de los valores en sí.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, ha funcionado a la perfección.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás te sirva filtrar solo los que no poseen un 0 en la variable RatioTalkOver y RatioSilenceTime, digamos que tu base de datos se llama "base" esto quedaría algo asi como:

```
base.1 <-
  base %>% filter(RatioTalkOver != 0 & RatioSilenceTime != 0) %>%
  group_by(ResumenOperadorPorMes, Centro) %>%
  summarise(
    RatioTalkOver = mean(RatioTalkOver),
    RatioSilenceTime = mean(RatioSilenceTime)
  )
```

Comment: Gracias Bastian por tu tiempo, me ha venido bien aprender otra forma de hacerlo, si bien he dado por válida la del compañero Patricio porque considero que es la que más se ajusta a mis necesidades.